# change case with regex

Tags: regex, uppercase, lowercase, camelcasing

I want to convert this text

`font-size-18`

to this

`fontSize18`

using Regex. Here is my trail:

`let conv = str => str.replace(/\-[a-z]/gi,/[A-Z]/gi);`

but it doesn't work, I can do it without Regex. But I want to make it with Regex, can this be done using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the dash followed by a single character, and use a replacer function that returns that character `toUpperCase`:

```js
const dashToCamel = str => str.replace(/-(\w)/g, (_, g1) => g1.toUpperCase());
console.log(dashToCamel("font-size-18"));
```

This assumes that all dashes are followed by word characters (though you could use `.` instead of `\w`). Note that since it looks like you want to replace *all* dashes, you should match and replace all dashes, not just dashes followed by alphabetical characters.

Comment: Great, I want to replace only dashes followed by characters. Your code works will but I have a question: why the " _ " in this replace function ? I guess it should be " - "

Comment: That's an *argument* not a string. The first argument is the full match, which is unnecessary - we only want to replace with the *first captured group* (which is the second argument), upper-cased.

Answer (score 1):

Your replace function uses `-[a-z]` which would only match `-s` and will [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that with `/[A-Z]/gi`.

You might make the match a bit more specific to capture all the parts without the dashes in a capturing group and use toUpperCase for the group (group 2) that captures the `s`

`([a-z]+)-([a-z])([a-z]*)-(\d+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP9382/1)

**That will match**

- `([a-z]+)` Capture 1+ times a-z into group 1
- `-` Match literally
- `([a-z])` Capture single a-z into group 2
- `([a-z]*)` Capture 0+ times a-z into group 3
- `-` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits into group 4

```js
const conv = str => str.replace(
  /([a-z]+)-([a-z])([a-z]*)-(\d+)/g,
  (_, p1, p2, p3, p4) => p1 + p2.toUpperCase() + p3 + p4
);
console.log(conv("font-size-18"));
```

Comment: a bit complicated but awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy I have added an explanation for the regex.

Comment: ok now what is p1,p2,p3,p4 ?

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy Those are the numbers of the captured groups which [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) can access.

Comment: Oh good, and the "_" in this  (_, p1, p2, p3, p4) => p1 + p2.toUpperCase() ?

Answer (score -1):

echo font-size-18 | sed "s/-s/S/g" | sed "s/-1/1/g"

Comment: oops, doesn't work?!

Comment: It's not even in the right language

Comment: copy and paste it in a terminal and hit enter :|

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but I want it in javascript. I guess this is Php

Comment: Aha. That's with `sed` with _bash_